# VB Net RegEx Match Multiple

Tags: regex, vb.net, multiline

I am trying to match with RegEx multiple lines to be grouped together. Here is an example of text I am searching:

```
Total
2015
DOLLAR
AMOUNT
Oct-15 DIFF 15-16
Total
2015
COMPANY 1 - WI
Nuts $ 59.85 $ 0.00 $ 135.45 $ 0.00 $ 135.45 $0.00
Bolts $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $0.00
Screws $ 449.20 $ 0.00 $ 541.23 $ 0.00 $ 541.23 $0.00
Total 7765: $ 509.05 $ 0.00 $ 676.68 $ 0.00 $ 676.68 $0.00
Company 2 - NE
Nuts $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $0.00
Bolts $ 0.00 $ 55.67 $ 542.48 $ 719.82 $(177.34) $777.02
Total 1876: $ 0.00 $ 55.67 $ 2,960.52 $ 4,265.82 $(1,305.30) $5,854.60
Company 3 - MN
Nuts $ 109.52 $ 606.52 $ 858.36 $ 606.52 $ 251.84 $606.52
Paper $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 483.82 $ 0.00 $ 483.82 $678.30
Gas $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $0.00
OTHER $ 521.49 $ 0.00 $ 521.49 $ 0.00 $ 521.49 $0.00
Total 6524: $ 631.01 $ 606.52 $ 3,909.09 $ 606.52 $ 3,302.57 $1,284.82
Company 4 - IA
Anything $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $0.00
Other $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 171.90 $ 0.00 $ 171.90 $0.00
Total 1123: $ 0.00 $ 0.00 $ 171.90 $ 0.00 $ 171.90 $0.00
```

I am trying to pull out the company names and the total line in groups. If I set it to multi-line and use

```
^(.+?\s-\s.{2})$
```

That will get me the company name. I have also tried this:

```
^(.+\s-\s\w{2}|Total\s\d{1,5}:.+)$
```

That will get both lines and will work but they are both coming through as group 1. Is there a way to make sure they match up? So group 1 would be the company name and group 2 would be the total line? I tried adding something like this in the middle but it did not work because there are a different number of lines in between the companies and total lines.

```
^(.+\s-\s\w{2})$(^.+$){1,20}^(Total\s\d{1,5}:.+)$
```

(I don't remember exactly what I had but it was giving me the middle lines..just not always the correct number of them.) Is there a way to skip those lines in between the company names and their respective total line and have group 1 be the customer name and group 2 be the total line?

Comment: I should add that it is not "company 1" or "company 2" but it does always start at the beginning of the line and contain " - XX" for the state. I just want that whole line and I can split it for name and state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I was looking for with this:

```
^(.*\s-\s\w{2})$\n(^.+$\n)+?^Total\s(\d{2,5}:.+)$
```

It gives me the customer name in group 1 and the total line in group 3 and I can ignore group 2. Thanks.

Comment: I changed it to this: ^(.* - \w{2})$\n(?>^.+$\n)+?^TOTAL\s(\d{2,5}:.+)$ so that I only get group 1 and group 2. I learned about non capturing patterns. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(.+\s-\s\w{2})$|^(Total\s\d{1,5}:.+)$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8r8ZS0/1

Comment: That does something close to what I had before (although it does separate them into groups). The problem is that when I cycle through the matches, I will have to keep track of which one I am on. I would like to be able to cycle through and get the customer name and total in one pass if it is possible. I would like Match 1 to have Group 1 AND Group2 together. Easier to loop through.

Comment: @J_K_M_A_N non capturing patterns can indeed help clean up the results. Hope you can read the results better now.